# Issue while filtering out a string with special characters and numbers in Pnadas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have `data frame(location)` as shown below. I have also pasted my current code below but it filters out all record containing numbers and specials characters.

My issue lies when there is a space character between words eg NEWYORK CITY , NEW YORK CITY . I dont filter out space character between  words .

**INPUT**

`location.head(8)`

```
    CITY        COUNTRY
    AGNIN34         FR
    (REYDON)        GB
    MARSCIANO       IT
   SANXIANG TOWN    CN
    SIZIANO         IT
    APELDOORN       NL
    REYDON          GB
    NEWYORK CITY    US
```

My current code:

```
out = location[location.apply(lambda c: c.str.match('(?i)[a-z]+$')).all(1)]
```

**Expected Output**

```
        CITY        COUNTRY
        MARSCIANO       IT
       SANXIANG TOWN    CN
        SIZIANO         IT
        APELDOORN       NL
        REYDON          GB
        NEWYORK CITY    US
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
out = location[location.CITY.astype(str).str.match('^[a-zA-Z ]*$')]
```

Comment: Getting an error -Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values

Comment: @aeapen add astype

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.contains` along with the `na=False` flag set:

```py
out = location[location["CITY"].str.contains(r'^[A-Za-z ]+$', na=False, regex=True)]
```